# Spring Webflux has huge performance drop from webFilter to controller

Tags: spring-boot, performance, spring-webflux

> spring webflux version: 2.7.2

I tested a simple webflux project (although I tested with SSL/TLS, I believe the problem would still exist without them), and I found problems with titles like: "HTTP request returns immediately after entering webFilter" and "HTTP returns as soon as the request enters the controller", there is a huge performance difference between the two cases.

TPS tested with Apache Bench in the case of 4-cores CPU:

- "Return as soon as the HTTP request enters the webFilter" = 67000
- "The HTTP request will return immediately after entering the controller" = 20000 ~ 30000

Some additional conditions are added:

- In the webFilter, the only thing I do is add the `keep-alive` response header to the response, and then return the response. (code below)
- There is no code content that I added after the webFilter. The next piece of code I added is the controller
- no injection with `@Autowired` in the controller.
- The controller method uses `@RequestBody` to get parameters. The length of the input parameters is very small. Take the following code as an example: message 16 bytes  (code below)

Code:

- MyFilter

```java
public class MyFilter implements WebFilter {
  
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("keep-alive", "true");
    
    // when i need to finish request
    return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance.wrap("hello".getBytes())));

    // when i don't need to finish request
    return chain.filter(exchange);
  }
}
```

- MyController:

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {
  
  @PostMapping("/hello")
  public Mono<HelloBody> hello(@RequestBody HelloBody helloBody) {
    return Mono.just(helloBody);
  }

  public static class HelloBody {
    private String message;

    // get/set
  }
}
```

As can be seen from the above code, such a test does not involve any business.

What I want to know is why there is such a big difference in performance returned by these two scenarios. More importantly, how can I reduce the performance loss of this part, so as to strive for more room for improvement in the performance of my program.

Comment: those two scenarios aren't equivalent (one parses the request body, the other does not, the second scenario might return JSON, not plain text, etc). It's hard to answer such a question without knowing more about the benchmark setup. We're running benchmarks ourselves and we're always trying to lower the overhead of our stack. I think the next step here is to use a profiler and potentially show where the difference is at runtime.

Comment: additional note: if the benchmark runs both client and server on the same host, you're merely testing the local TCP stack. WebFlux shines when dealing with latency in general and stable response time under concurrency. For such scenario (no latency, blocking calls) Spring MVC might perform better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Today we tested again returning plain text in the controller, but the result is the same. I understand that the controller will parse the request message, but even if @RequestBody is removed, there is still a big performance gap. I appreciate the great convenience your team brings to java. Can I make any configuration changes, such as opening more threads or adjusting some parameter values, to reduce the performance drop in this part?

Comment: Sorry, the above understanding is not necessarily correct: even if @RequestBody is removed, webflux still seems to parse the request message internally. We supplemented the test, using exchange in the controller to return the result directly, so that the performance drop obtained by the test is not too serious: from 20~30k to about 48k.

Comment: @TJwoods -- can you make a complete sample available which demonstrates the problem?